# Authentication failed when pushing to a repository on GitHub (from GitHub Desktop and command line)

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

- I am using GitHub Desktop v2.5.7 and Git v2.29.1 on Windows 10 64 bit.
- My GitHub account has [2FA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) enabled.
- I can clone repositories from GitHub using the GitHub Desktop or command line
- I have generated an SSL key and followed all instructions to add it locally and to GitHub
- I have generated a personal access token and tried using this in the command line, and also my password

**Problem: When I attempt to push changes to a repository I get an authentication error.**

Error in GitHub Desktop:

[image: Screenshot of error - authentication failed. Some common reasons include...]

Error in command line:

With sslverify turned on:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jacquibo/neo4jDataSets.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

With sslverify turned off:

> info: please complete authentication in your browser... 
> fatal: incorrect_client_credentials: The client_id and/or client_secret passed are incorrect. [https://docs.github.com/apps/managing-oauth-apps/troubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors/#incorrect-client-credentials] 
> Username for 'https://github.com': my@githubemail.co.uk 
> Password for 'https://my@githubemail.co.uk@github.com': 
> remote: No anonymous write access. 
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git/'

I have tried:

- all the suggestions in the error in GitHub
- adding an SSH key locally and on GitHub (when I use `ssh -i mycertname -vT git@github.com` I get a permission denied message, see below)
- adding a personal access token
- checking origin is using HTTPS

Error using the command line to test SSL certificate:

> OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020 
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
> debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22. 
> debug1: connect to address 140.82.121.4 port 22: Permission denied 
> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Permission denied

How can I fix this problem?

Only being able to edit files actually on GitHub.com is not very practical.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use SSH to access the repository, not HTTPS.

Change the URL for the remote from `https://xxx` to `git://xxx`.

You can use the green button towards the right side of the GitHub repository code page to help you get the correct URL. Change from:

[image: HTTPS URL]

to

[image: SSH URL]

The other thing you need to do is make sure you have an up-to-date local installation of Git. You may run into errors if you have an old version of Git installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of not having an SSH key in your GitHub account.
Follow the documentation to install SSH key to your GitHub account.

*[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)*